# ValueError with Apply function

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I need your help please with the below function I wrote. I need to check it is True and True, create the column 'Median Signal' and put 1. Else, put 0.

```
def Assign_median():
    if Pri.loc['28-6-2015'].isnull().T==True & X['12 days check']==True:
        X['Median signal']=1
    else:
        X['Median signal']=0

Final.apply(Assign_median())
```

I get the error :**ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().**

Please note that,
`X['12 days check']` is a boolean column. `Pri.loc['28-6-2015'].isnull().T` has the same length of `X['12 days check']`

Appreciate your help with this code.

**Update**
The code works if I extracted the column from the newly created dataframe (.isnull() returns a dataframe).

````
    if ((Pri.loc['28-6-2015'].isnull().T)['28-6-2015']==True) & (X['12 days check']==True):
        X['Median signal']=1
    else:
        X['Median signal']=0

Final.apply(Assign_median())```

The code this way doesnt look neat. Any help with this? Can I use something instead of .isnull() to return a series?
````

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? It will be easier to work. Your if condition has a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `axis=1` parameter as you wan to apply it to row.

```
Final.apply(Assign_median, axis=1)
```

On the side note, you can just pass function to apply, you dont need to call

Comment: unfortunately, it is not the reason. On a side note, how to paste from excel spreadsheet to stackoverflow? I tried this, but it doesnt work https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: I dont think you can paste it directly anyhow. try putting round brackets around both conditions like `if ( () & () )`

Comment: I already separated with brackets but same issue. Anyway, I think I solved it but it doesnt look neat. So .isnull() creates a dataframe. So I need to specify the column am comparing to. So changing the code to the below works. ```def Assign_median():
    if (Pri.loc['28-6-2015'].isnull().T)['28-6-2015']==True & X['12 days check']==True:
        X['Median signal']=1
    else:
        X['Median signal']=0

Final.apply(Assign_median())``` So any suggestion to rewrite this nicely?

Comment: I will add it to the question to look better.

Comment: why dont you just do `if (Pri.loc['28-6-2015'].isnull()) & (X['12 days check']==True)`

Comment: Also, why are you calling function in the apply? you dont need to. Futher, i think you need to pas row into function `def Assign_median(X):     if (Pri.loc['28-6-2015'].isnull().T)['28-6-2015']==True & X['12 days check']==True:         X['Median signal']=1     else:         X['Median signal']=0  Final.apply(Assign_median()) `